# porting 32 to 64b printf related errors

Tags: c, printf, 32bit-64bit, porting

I am trying to port code from 32b to 64bit and i am stuck on this one error.

```
      printf ("STUFF 0x%x ",(u_int32_t)val)
```

On porting i get an error saying %x expects argument of type unsigned int and argument 2 is of type "long unsigned int". So taking this error into account i make the change of %x to %lx

```
      printf ("STUFF 0x%lx ",(u_int32_t)val)
```

format %x expects argument of type long unsigned int and argument 2 is of type unsigned int. This is really confusing.

Now i do something like this and it works.

```
      printf ("STUFF 0x%x ",(u_int32_t)(size_t)val)
```

I am not sure why this solves the problem too. Now sure what is the right way to fix this error.

Adding one more question here.

So u have a structure st;

```
   st *a = NULL;
   u_int32_t = B

   a = (st *)B;
```

I get a error here saying "cast to pointer from integer of different size". I fix this by doing something like

```
  a = (st *)(size_t)B;
```

Is this the right way of doing it ?

Comment: What type is `val` *really*?

Comment: Its actually a structure object ..  Struct a {}  
void myfunc(a *val){
printf ("STUFF 0x%lx ",(u_int32_t)val)
}

//Something like this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to print a pointer then use the `"%p"` format specifier:

```
printf("STUFF %p\n", val);
```

See e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: Alternatively, he may cast it to `uintptr_t` and use the `PRIxPTR` specifier to print it as an integer.